# Shutting Down Spring Integration (with RabbitMQ) Cleanly

Tags: spring-integration, spring-rabbit

I am using : Spring Boot 1.4.7, Spring Integration 4.3.10, RabbitMQ 3.6.5

I have a Spring Boot application that has several Spring Integration flows that both send and receive messages to a rabbitMQ broker.

I am having an issue where when the "shutdown" actuator is called the application does not always shutdown cleanly.

After doing a thread dump, I can see that a single  "SimpleMessageListenerContainer" thread is blocked on a "send" operation to the broker:

```
"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer#0-1" #81 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fe49bcac800 nid=0x4fc5 waiting on condition [0x00007fe489efe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c259a6f8> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:458)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.put(SynchronousQueue.java:877)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel.doSend(QueueChannel.java:93)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:358)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:269)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:186)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:188)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$1100(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.processMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:246)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:203)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:823)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:746)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:99)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:191)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1238)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:727)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1176)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1100(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:99)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1370)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Updated information based on the feedback from Gary:**

I went back through all of our channel definitions (we use the spring integration DSL) and most of them are defined as follows:

```
public MessageChannel channelIdMailOut() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}
```

However, I did find a couple of outliers:

```
@Bean(name=CHANNEL_NAME_ID_MAIL_IN)
public MessageChannel channelIdMailIn() {
    //Using a rendezvous channel on inbound because we use a rest endpoint to pull messages rather than using a push model
    return MessageChannels.rendezvous().get();
}
@Bean(name=CHANNEL_NAME_CATEGORY_REFRESH_PRODUCTION_OUT)
public MessageChannel channelCategoryRefreshProductionOut() {
    return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
}
```

I appreciate the quick feedback, I will explore this avenue further.

Comment: It has nothing to do with RabbitMQ - the thread is stuck in an in-memory queue; see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> at org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel.doSend(QueueChannel.java:93)

It looks like you are using a bounded `QueueChannel` downstream of the inbound channel adapter...

```
adapter->DirectChannel->someEndpoint->QueueChannel<-somePoller
```

...and the queue is full. Since you are stopping the context; the poller thread that's reading from the queue will never free up space.

You don't show your configuration, but you can set a `sendTimeout` on the endpoint that is sending to the `QueueChannel` and the send will timeout.

However, it's generally not a good idea to use a `QueueChannel` in this scenario, unless you don't mind message loss. Messages that are in the queue when you shut down will be lost.

**EDIT**

To answer your comment below.

There are several options...

1. Add a send-timeout to the endpoint that sends to the `RendezvousChannel`; it should be less than the `shutDownTimeout` on the inbound adapter's listener container.
2. Use an external `taskExecutor` in the amqp inbound adapter and use `executor.shutDownNow()` (or `setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(false)` for a Spring executor), which will interrupt the thread trying to post the RC - this might cause some noise in the log because the container will try to restart the consumer thread.
3. Manually `stop()` the inbound channel adapter before shutting down the executor (which should avoid the log noise).
4. Add an `IntegrationMBeanExporter` and call `stopActiveComponents()` with a timeout to allow things to quiesce.

For 3 and 4, if you can bump your spring-rabbit version to 1.7.3, you can use an `ApplicationListemer<AsyncConsumerStoppedEvent>` to get a notification that the container thread terminated.

Comment: Gary, after doing some digging it looks like the RendezvousChannel is my issue because it extends the QueueChannel. Is there way to properly close this channel down prior/after I issue a shutdown on the context? We need to support this silly thing because we have a legacy ColdFusion (yes CF) that polls an end point to check for messages on the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow-up on the solution that worked for me. Option #2 worked like a charm. I created a new task executor and set waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown to "false". Gary, thanks very much for the help!

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutorIdMailIn(
        @Value("${taskExecutor.idMailIn.corePoolSize:4}") int corePoolSize,
        @Value("${taskExecutor.idMailIn.maxPoolSize:4}") int maxPoolSize, 
        @Value("${taskExecutor.idMailIn.queueCapacity:0}") int queueCapacity) {

    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("taskExecutorIdMailIn-");
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(corePoolSize);
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
    if (queueCapacity > 0) {
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(queueCapacity);
    }
    taskExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new CallerRunsPolicy());
    taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(false);
    return taskExecutor;
}   

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flowRabbitToIdMailIn(ConnectionFactory factory, @Qualifier("taskExecutorIdMailIn") TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(factory, queueNameIdMail)
                    .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
                    .errorHandler(errorHandler)
            )
            .transform(Transformers.fromJson())
            .channel(CHANNEL_NAME_ID_MAIL_IN)
            .get();
}
```